# make all fatal error,when i make caffe

Tags: python, anaconda, deep-learning, caffe

I compiled caffe on manjaro.When I run make all in the caffe root folder,I get:

```
 CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin 
/usr/bin/ld: .build_release/tools/caffe.o: undefined reference to  symbol '_ZdlPvm'
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error：ld return 1
make: ***[Makefile:620：.build_release/tools/caffe.bin] error 1
```

How can I fix this?
This is some of my Makefile.config:

```
 CPU_ONLY := 1

 OPENCV_VERSION := 3

 BLAS := open

 ANACONDA_HOME := /home/xdp/anaconda2
 PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
     $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
     $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include \

 PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

go threw [caffe installation guide](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html).

before building caffe, make sure you install:

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libboost-all-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev protobuf-compiler libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip gfortran
```

then, try to build build caffe that way:

```
cd caffe
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
and change setting in Makefile.config
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
./configure
make all
```